# What is the flaw in this string comparison logic?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

The following

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned short int stringCompare ( char * s1, char * s2 )
{
// returns 1 if the character arrays s1 and s2 are equal; 
// returns 0 otherwise
    while (*s1 && (*s1++ == *s2++));
    return (!(*s1) && !(*s2));
}

int main () 
{
    char str1 [] = "americano";
    char str2 [] = "americana";
    std::cout << stringCompare(str1,str2);
    return 0;
}
```

prints `1`, meaning my function's logic is incorrect. I'd like to understand why. Let me explain my logic:

```
while (*s1 && (*s1++ == *s2++))
```

simultaneously increments pointers `s1` and `s2` so long as s1 is not equal to `'\0'` and the value `s1` points to is the same as the value `s2` points to. It is supposed to be a shorter way of writing

```
while (*s1 && *s2)
{
   if (*s1 != *s2) break;
   ++s1; ++s2;
}
```

and relies on fancy operator precedence to shorten it.

The statement

```
return (!(*s1) && !(*s2))
```

means

```
"If s1 and s2 are both the null character, return true; otherwise return false"
```

because if the strings are equal then `s1` and `s2` will both be the null character after the `while` loop.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Have you considered simply stepping through the algorithm? You'll very quickly find the problem...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The flaw is that the `++` is done in the loop even on the last character, when they don't match. If the following character matches (which it does in this case, the null terminator) then they compare as true.

Comment: Yeah; I'd write `while (*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)) { s1++; s2++; }` Or something.

Comment: Oh ... so it doesn't short circuit?

Comment: @CrappyProgrammer the `&&` short circuits if the first condition is met, but in this case it wasn't.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the post increment operator

```
while (*s1 && (*s1++ == *s2++));
```

when you increment `s1` after comparison of the last non-null character, the comparison returns false, but the pointers are incremented anyway. The false evaluation leads to the while loop terminating. But the next line you use the condition that the pointers both point to null characters (which they do) to indicate a string match (which was not a match). Thus your code will consider any strings to match even if their last character does not match.

Comment: The increment isn't necessarily **after** comparison. What happens is that the values used for the comparison are the values at the previous sequence point and at the next sequence point the pointers will have been incremented. There is no specific order to do the increments and comparison in. *Thinking of it that way is a simplified view that may induce errors in more complicated expressions.*

Comment: @pmg Yes fair point it is badly worded. I have edited it to try to better explain.